# Why not define tensors under Galilean or Poincare transformations?

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, vectors, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

I have seen vectors (and tensors, in general) defined under rotations,
$$V^i=R^i_{~j}V^j$$
and under Lorentz transformations,
$$V^{\prime\mu}=\Lambda^\mu_{~~\nu}V^\nu$$
where $R,\Lambda$ are the matrices representing rotations and Lorentz transformations.

My definition of tensors is old-fashioned i.e., in terms of how a bunch of numbers transforms under rotation or Lorentz transformations.

Why doesn't one talk about vectors (and tensors, in general) under the Galilean or Poincare transformations (or groups)? Wouldn't that be more general? Why doesn't one define tensors under translations, spatial, or spacetime? Please do not use more sophisticated definitions of tensors as it will be very painful for me to follow.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilei-covariant_tensor_formulation

Comment: Tensor transformation are defined on a tangent plane corresponding to a given point on a manifold. Galilean or Poincare transformation also involves spacetime translation, so they are not on the same tangent plane

Comment: I recommend studying spherical tensors with Schur-Weyl duality, and then maybe the Robinson–Schensted correspondence. It really explains tensors as the things that exist because they transform properly. Coordinates be damned.

Comment: Representations of the Poincare group which are finite dimensional (a pre-requisite for writing a tensor that way) are not very useful in physics. I was about to say they don't exist but Wikipedia proved me wrong.

Comment: Maybe it is worth a comment that **events** (instead of vectors) transform they way you want.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't one talk about vectors under the Galilean or Poincare transformations (or groups)? Wouldn't that be more general?

The tuple $(V^1,\ldots,V^n)$ is interpreted as the representation of some vector $V$ w.r.t. a basis. That being said, if we fix two bases, then the transformation of vector components is obviously linear (e.g. a rotation or a Lorentz transformation as you said). But Galilean transformations and Poincaré transformations are affine transformations.

The generalization you are looking for is the [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group), the transformations between two arbitary bases. The point is that euclidean spaces and Minkowski space do not only have an [affine structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space), but also come with a bilinear form on the translation space. Each chart has an orthonormal basis associated to it and the transformation of vector components from one coordinate system to another is precisely the differential of the coordinate transformation (i.e. a Lorentz transformation in the case of Minkowski space).

Comment: General affine group, actually, not general linear group. A transform x ↦ ax is linear, while x ↦ ax + b is affine. It can be made linear by adding an extra coordinate and constraining it to be 1. More generally, transforms between vectors spaces are linear, while those between affine spaces are affine. That's all, as seen and described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group

Comment: @NinjaDarth My point is that the transformation of vector components is always linear, not affine. The transformation of **events** can be affine. Don't you agree?

Comment: Right. But there is actually an affine version of tangent spaces. I think it involves rolling tangents and rolling connections. I'm still not perfectly clear on it, yet. Either affine varieties, or affine bundles (or both). This is one item a search brings up. https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~noonan/rolling.pdf